# copy every cells in a column to particular cell in new sheet every time with a loop

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I seek your help to copy the cell values in (column D) of the first worksheet to a specified cell location in 16 existing worksheets

i want value in
D2 in in sheet1 to sheet2 (G5)

D3 in in sheet1 to sheet3 (G5)

D4 in in sheet1 to sheet4 (G5)

and so on until the D16 is copied to G5 of sheet16

i am a newbie, i looked into several answers and tried to work out on my own but.... nothing happened

```
Sub latitude()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For I = 1 To WS_Count
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Range("d2").Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
'at this point i want it to copy "D3" on next loop
ActiveSheet.Range("G5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Loop
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
' and because the "Sheets("Calculations").Select" above takes it to the first sheet the whole script is a waste till now
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: is there a reason why you don't just use dynamic content? like `='sheet1'!D3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alistairs attempt is good, i would however not use `shtname = "Sheet" & i`, instead try the following solution and think about bulletprooving it a bit (existance of worksheets) ;)

```
Sub Copy_to_G5()
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    i = 2
    Do Until i = 17
        With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Copy
        .Worksheets(i).Range("G5").PasteSpecial
        End With
    i = i + 1
    Loop

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: because of the WITH statement - instead of writing ThisWorkbook before every `.` you can say `With ThisWorkbook`, then the `.` is a connector to this with statement - especially great in complex range/cells stuff.

Comment: Thanks Jook, but i had to make a small modification to make it work though! had to remove the `.` (DOT) infront of both the `.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Copy` and `.Worksheets(i).Range("G5").PasteSpecial` and i want to know why that is so if you please to explain and thanks again

Comment: Very good, forgot about the built in index for worksheets! Uttam - I'm a bit confused about having to remove the `.` to make it work. The `.` is necessary when using a `With` statement.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that too, but it is like this: using `.Worksheets(i)`, one is refering to the worksheets of the workbook this macro is executed in (_ThisWorkbook_); using `Worksheets(i)` is referring by default to _ActiveWorkbook_, like if you had `Application.Worksheets(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copy_to_G5()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim shtname As String

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    i = 2
    Do Until i = 17
        shtname = "Sheet" & i
        sht1.Cells(i, 4).Copy
        Sheets(shtname).Range("G5").PasteSpecial
    i = i + 1
    Loop

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Alistair 
I tried the macro but it only succeeds in copying once into sheet2, nothing after that. 
i created a dummy workbook to test this macro because i forgot to mention earlier that i had randomly named sheets.
Thank you

Comment: Ok the reason it hasn't worked is because the sheet names are different, I assumed they were "Sheet 2- Sheet 16". I will try and think of a solution around different worksheet names.